# How to correctly debug a silent failure?

Tags: vba, outlook

I wrote myself a small message filter, for simplicity assume

```
Sub MyFilter(Item As Outlook.MailItem)
    MsgBog ("MyFilter: " & Item.Subject)
End Sub
```

, that I wanted to test via the macro

```
Sub TestMyFilter()
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    For Each objItem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
        MsgBox ("objItem: " & objItem.Subject)
        MyFilter (objItem)
        MsgBox ("done")
    Next
End Sub
```

assigned to a button. When I select one (or more) mails and have the button run `TestMyFilter`, I see the first message box for the first mail selected, but afterwards nothing else happens. In debug mode, the last executed line is `MyFilter (objItem)`, after which pressing F8 simply results in the execution ending without any output or error whatsoever.

How can I determine the problem? I meanwhile figured out I forgot to `Call` the Sub `MyFilter`, but should I have figured that out?

Comment: normally you shouldn't have to write `call` before your statement. It should work like it is, but remove the parentheses, which I suspect are the issue. FOr your questio, there's an option in the VBE to "Break on all errors"

Comment: @iDevlop Thanks, "Break on all errors" should be the accepted answer actually, can you post it as such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in the VBE to "Break on all errors". This is the way to go when nothing else works :-)